# xmodmap doesn't work anymore after upgrading to 22.04

Tags: scripts, updates, bind, xmodmap, keys

I upgraded to the latest 22.04 LTS version this morning and after that my xmodmap script doesn't work anymore, i'm curious if something has changed that is causing the script to not work anymore. I use this script so I can bind 'jikl' in combination with CAPSLOCK as my arrow keys for easy navigation. This my xmodmap script:

```
keycode 66 = Mode_switch
keysym j = j J Left
keysym l = l L Right
keysym i = i I Up
keysym k = k K Down
```

~

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason why it does not work anymore: upgrading to 22.04 has now put you on the Wayland server, where the classical tools for Xorg do not anymore work.

You can switch to Xorg again by logging out, then before entering your password, clicking the cog wheel to select the "Ubuntu on xorg" session. That choice is remembered until you change it again.